# Assume function $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$,the $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=\infty$,so f'?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Assume function $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=\infty$,can we state "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f'(x)=\infty$"?

If it is true,please prove it.If it is false,please find an example which can  refute it.

I have trouble finding this ,so I hope you could help me.Thank you !

Comment: Maybe by contradiction : suppose $f'(x)<C,x>a-d,d>0$ then $f(a)-f(a-d)<Cd$ by integrating, hence if $f(a-d)$ is finite so $f(a)$ ?

Comment: Take $f(x) = \log\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$. $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \infty$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = -\infty$

Comment: @fwd Thank you sir.But I actually mean that I want the $f'(x)$ is finite while the $f(x)$ is infinite.If I only want to find the difference in sign,a more simple example is $1/x$

Comment: By the mean value theorem, if $|f'(x)| < M$ on $(a, b)$ then $|f(y) - f(x)| \leq M|y - x|$ for $x, y$ in $(a, b).$ What this says is that the derivative cannot be bounded if the function is to be unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample of your statement that *a differentiable function in $(0,1)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = +\infty$, must have $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)= \infty$ (meaning either $+$ or $-$ infinity)*.

Consider the function $$f(x) = \frac1x \left(1+\frac12\sin\frac1x\right).$$ We have, for $x>0$,
$$f(x) \geq \frac1{2x},$$
so that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty.$$

However we get
$$f'(x) = -\frac1{x^2} - \frac1{2x^2}\sin\frac1x-\frac1{2x^3} \cos \frac1x.$$

Consider the null sequence
$$a_n = \frac1{\frac{\pi}4+2n\pi}\ \ n=0,1,2\dots.$$
We have
$$f'(a_n) = -\frac12 \left(\frac{\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^2 
- \frac1{2\sqrt 2}
 \left(\frac{\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^2 - \frac1{2\sqrt 2} \left(\frac{\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^3,
$$
that clearly diverges to $-\infty$.

Now taking the null  sequence
$$b_n = \frac1{\frac{3\pi}4+2n\pi}\ \ n=0,1,2\dots$$
yields
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(b_n) &=& -\frac12 \left(\frac{3\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^2 
+ \frac1{2\sqrt 2}
 \left(\frac{3\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^2 + \frac1{2\sqrt 2} \left(\frac{3\pi}4 + 2n\pi\right)^3 > \\
&>&-\frac12 [2(n+1)\pi]^2+\frac1{2\sqrt 2}(2n\pi)^2+\frac1{2\sqrt 2} (2n\pi)^3,
\end{eqnarray}
which is therefore a sequence diverging to $+\infty$. Thus
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$$
**does not exist**.